# How to concatenate string and variable in autohotkey v2?

Tags: autohotkey

Here's a piece of code that works in v1:

```
Var1 := "Example"
%Var1%Variable := "Concatenated Variable"
MsgBox % ExampleVariable
```

This syntax however seems to be removed from v2. Is there any way I can do this in v2?

Comment: You resort to that when your language doesn't have proper hashmaps ("associative arrays"), which was the case in early versions of AutoHotkey, and for backward-compatibility reasons the feature remained all through the 1.x releases. AHK 2 already has associative arrays and so has done away with this tomfoolery.

Comment: What's the variable's type? (string, integer, etc)

Answer (score 1):

AHKv2 added [map objects](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Map.htm):

```
Variable := Map()
Var1 := "Example"
Variable[Var1] := "Key lookup"
MsgBox Variable["Example"]
```

Maps are better because you can see all the keys, iterate through them, copy them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In AHK version 2 variables cannot be created dynamically.  A variable can be assigned dynamically if it has been declared or referenced non-dynamically somewhere in the script.  https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Variables.htm#ref

**BELOW ARE TWO WORKAROUNDS:**

**1. PREDEFINE THE VARIABLE ExampleVariable**

```
;**PLACE IN VARIABLE DEFINITIONS**

ExampleVariable := ""

;**MANY STEPS GO HERE**

Var1 := "Example"

%Var1%Variable := "Concatenated Variable"

MsgBox ExampleVariable
```

**2. USE ANY OBJECT AS A TEMPORARY STORAGE**

```
Var1 := "Example"

Variable := {}

Variable.%Var1% := "Concatenated Variable"

MsgBox Variable.Example

Variable := ""
```